# Hiding a Anchor Tag with a specific url

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am Implementing Webview in android application... I want to hide a Specific  tag like with a specific href how can i do this...

Example: i want to hide second  tag with href="/track.php?id=icmo" how  to ? as their is no class or id for  tag

```
<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/track.php?id=ycmo"> … </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>

<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/track.php?id=icmo"> … </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>

<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/track.php?id=kcmo"> … </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>

<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/track.php?id=mcmo"> … </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to get all the anchors, iterate over them to find the one with the matching href atttribute, and then hide it

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=anchors.length; i--;) {
    if ( anchors[i].getAttribute('href') == '/track.php?id=icmo' ) {
        anchors[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A2T94/)

Comment: I have one more qus... whow can we hide href which contains some words like 'if ( anchors[i].getAttribute('href').contains'track.php') {
        anchors[i].style.display = 'none';
    }'